# DSL Query in Kibana Discover not working as Kibana Dev tools

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-6

Below are MappingIndex, Value Inserted and Nested Search query with inner hits

** Creating Elastic Mapping Index**

```
PUT employee
{
    "mappings": {
        "emp_db": {
            "properties": {
                "emp_group": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "company": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "employee": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "first": {
                                            "type": "text",
                                            "fielddata": true
                                        },
                                        "last": {
                                            "type": "text",
                                            "fielddata": true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

** Inserting Few Values on the Elastic Index Mapping created **

```
PUT employee/_doc/1
{
  "emp_group" : "000001",
  "company": [
      {
            "employee": {
                "first": "Alice",
                "last":"Smith"
              }
            },
            {
            "employee":{
                "first": "Pat",
                "last":"Smith"
              }
            },
            {
            "employee":{
                "first": "Alice",
                "last":"Hazelwood"
            }
        }
  ]
}
```

** Nested Query Inner hits(its working in Kibana Dev Tools but not in Kibana Discover) **

```
GET employee/_search
{
  "_source":false,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "company",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "company.employee.first": "Alice" }},
            { "match": { "company.employee.last": "Smith" }}
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {

          "_source": false,
          "docvalue_fields": [
            "company.employee.first",
            "company.employee.last"
            ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above nested inner hit query working perfectly and giving me proper result in Kibana Dev Tools, 
but  when I am running the same query  in Kibana Discover (filter-> Edit Query DSL) its giving me no result.

Any help much appreciated ..